# Unity shell restarting periodically for no apparent reason

Tags: unity, 20.04, crash

My Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS Unity shell is restarting periodically, sometimes once a day, sometimes three times in a row. It closes all the applications except for Terminal, Files windows, system update dialog, and sometimes others, but usually not.

I've had the same issue before in Ubuntu 19.10.

Here's the syslog from the crash:

```
Aug 26 23:17:27 beast systemd-resolved[1253]: Server returned error NXDOMAIN, mitigating potential DNS violation DVE-2018-0001, retrying transaction with reduced feature level UDP.
Aug 26 23:17:28 beast dockerd[2035]: time="2020-08-26T23:17:28.032798321+02:00" level=error msg="collecting stats for d64358a43e6a940fc352948fd2368ac5d200a729a5b6ba99e531f9bae3923cd2: no such container"
Aug 26 23:17:28 beast dockerd[2035]: time="2020-08-26T23:17:28.035448508+02:00" level=error msg="collecting stats for 73233e95b937634ced5f03cb6dd3c3a2bdbd8a8a1be5390272247920e34f2f90: no such container"
Aug 26 23:17:29 beast dockerd[2035]: time="2020-08-26T23:17:29.038435017+02:00" level=error msg="collecting stats for d64358a43e6a940fc352948fd2368ac5d200a729a5b6ba99e531f9bae3923cd2: no such container"
Aug 26 23:17:29 beast dockerd[2035]: time="2020-08-26T23:17:29.040647835+02:00" level=error msg="collecting stats for 73233e95b937634ced5f03cb6dd3c3a2bdbd8a8a1be5390272247920e34f2f90: no such container"
Aug 26 23:17:30 beast dockerd[2035]: time="2020-08-26T23:17:30.044828305+02:00" level=error msg="collecting stats for d64358a43e6a940fc352948fd2368ac5d200a729a5b6ba99e531f9bae3923cd2: no such container"
Aug 26 23:17:30 beast dockerd[2035]: time="2020-08-26T23:17:30.046683184+02:00" level=error msg="collecting stats for 73233e95b937634ced5f03cb6dd3c3a2bdbd8a8a1be5390272247920e34f2f90: no such container"
Aug 26 23:17:31 beast dockerd[2035]: time="2020-08-26T23:17:31.047730460+02:00" level=error msg="collecting stats for d64358a43e6a940fc352948fd2368ac5d200a729a5b6ba99e531f9bae3923cd2: no such container"
Aug 26 23:17:31 beast dockerd[2035]: time="2020-08-26T23:17:31.049981440+02:00" level=error msg="collecting stats for 73233e95b937634ced5f03cb6dd3c3a2bdbd8a8a1be5390272247920e34f2f90: no such container"
Aug 26 23:17:32 beast dockerd[2035]: time="2020-08-26T23:17:32.054518337+02:00" level=error msg="collecting stats for 73233e95b937634ced5f03cb6dd3c3a2bdbd8a8a1be5390272247920e34f2f90: no such container"
Aug 26 23:17:32 beast dockerd[2035]: time="2020-08-26T23:17:32.057609151+02:00" level=error msg="collecting stats for d64358a43e6a940fc352948fd2368ac5d200a729a5b6ba99e531f9bae3923cd2: no such container"
Aug 26 23:17:33 beast dockerd[2035]: time="2020-08-26T23:17:33.058327671+02:00" level=error msg="collecting stats for d64358a43e6a940fc352948fd2368ac5d200a729a5b6ba99e531f9bae3923cd2: no such container"
Aug 26 23:17:33 beast dockerd[2035]: time="2020-08-26T23:17:33.060558553+02:00" level=error msg="collecting stats for 73233e95b937634ced5f03cb6dd3c3a2bdbd8a8a1be5390272247920e34f2f90: no such container"
Aug 26 23:17:34 beast dockerd[2035]: time="2020-08-26T23:17:34.063207333+02:00" level=error msg="collecting stats for 73233e95b937634ced5f03cb6dd3c3a2bdbd8a8a1be5390272247920e34f2f90: no such container"
Aug 26 23:17:34 beast dockerd[2035]: time="2020-08-26T23:17:34.065389223+02:00" level=error msg="collecting stats for d64358a43e6a940fc352948fd2368ac5d200a729a5b6ba99e531f9bae3923cd2: no such container"
Aug 26 23:17:34 beast rtkit-daemon[1871]: Supervising 0 threads of 0 processes of 0 users.
Aug 26 23:17:34 beast rtkit-daemon[1871]: Successfully made thread 3168242 of process 3113 owned by '1000' RT at priority 5.
Aug 26 23:17:34 beast rtkit-daemon[1871]: Supervising 1 threads of 1 processes of 1 users.
Aug 26 23:17:35 beast dockerd[2035]: time="2020-08-26T23:17:35.067611343+02:00" level=error msg="collecting stats for 73233e95b937634ced5f03cb6dd3c3a2bdbd8a8a1be5390272247920e34f2f90: no such container"
Aug 26 23:17:35 beast dockerd[2035]: time="2020-08-26T23:17:35.069812198+02:00" level=error msg="collecting stats for d64358a43e6a940fc352948fd2368ac5d200a729a5b6ba99e531f9bae3923cd2: no such container"
Aug 26 23:17:36 beast dockerd[2035]: time="2020-08-26T23:17:36.072274940+02:00" level=error msg="collecting stats for 73233e95b937634ced5f03cb6dd3c3a2bdbd8a8a1be5390272247920e34f2f90: no such container"
Aug 26 23:17:36 beast dockerd[2035]: time="2020-08-26T23:17:36.074356540+02:00" level=error msg="collecting stats for d64358a43e6a940fc352948fd2368ac5d200a729a5b6ba99e531f9bae3923cd2: no such container"
Aug 26 23:17:37 beast dockerd[2035]: time="2020-08-26T23:17:37.076634902+02:00" level=error msg="collecting stats for 73233e95b937634ced5f03cb6dd3c3a2bdbd8a8a1be5390272247920e34f2f90: no such container"
Aug 26 23:17:37 beast dockerd[2035]: time="2020-08-26T23:17:37.078785552+02:00" level=error msg="collecting stats for d64358a43e6a940fc352948fd2368ac5d200a729a5b6ba99e531f9bae3923cd2: no such container"
Aug 26 23:17:38 beast dockerd[2035]: time="2020-08-26T23:17:38.081456291+02:00" level=error msg="collecting stats for d64358a43e6a940fc352948fd2368ac5d200a729a5b6ba99e531f9bae3923cd2: no such container"
Aug 26 23:17:38 beast dockerd[2035]: time="2020-08-26T23:17:38.083724905+02:00" level=error msg="collecting stats for 73233e95b937634ced5f03cb6dd3c3a2bdbd8a8a1be5390272247920e34f2f90: no such container"
Aug 26 23:17:38 beast systemd[3106]: unity7.service: State 'stop-sigterm' timed out. Killing.
Aug 26 23:17:38 beast systemd[3106]: unity7.service: Killing process 2722682 (_Postman) with signal SIGKILL.
Aug 26 23:17:38 beast systemd[3106]: unity7.service: Killing process 3167460 (_Postman) with signal SIGKILL.
Aug 26 23:17:38 beast systemd[3106]: unity7.service: Killing process 3167467 (_Postman) with signal SIGKILL.
Aug 26 23:17:38 beast systemd[3106]: unity7.service: Killing process 2722709 (gdbus) with signal SIGKILL.
Aug 26 23:17:38 beast systemd[3106]: unity7.service: Killing process 2722733 (_Postman) with signal SIGKILL.
Aug 26 23:17:38 beast systemd[3106]: unity7.service: Killing process 2722736 (ThreadPoolSingl) with signal SIGKILL.
Aug 26 23:17:38 beast systemd[3106]: unity7.service: Killing process 2722763 (CacheThread_Blo) with signal SIGKILL.
Aug 26 23:17:38 beast systemd[3106]: unity7.service: Killing process 3167452 (ThreadPoolForeg) with signal SIGKILL.
Aug 26 23:17:38 beast systemd[3106]: unity7.service: Killing process 3167462 (n/a) with signal SIGKILL.
Aug 26 23:17:38 beast systemd[3106]: unity7.service: Killing process 3167481 (n/a) with signal SIGKILL.
Aug 26 23:17:38 beast systemd[3106]: unity7.service: Killing process 3167483 (n/a) with signal SIGKILL.
Aug 26 23:17:38 beast systemd[3106]: unity7.service: Killing process 3167486 (n/a) with signal SIGKILL.
Aug 26 23:17:38 beast systemd[3106]: unity7.service: Killing process 3167487 (n/a) with signal SIGKILL.
Aug 26 23:17:38 beast systemd[3106]: unity7.service: Killing process 3167500 (ThreadPoolServi) with signal SIGKILL.
Aug 26 23:17:38 beast systemd[3106]: unity7.service: Killing process 3167501 (ThreadPoolForeg) with signal SIGKILL.
Aug 26 23:17:38 beast systemd[3106]: unity7.service: Killing process 3167503 (n/a) with signal SIGKILL.
Aug 26 23:17:38 beast systemd[3106]: unity7.service: Killing process 3168253 (n/a) with signal SIGKILL.
Aug 26 23:17:38 beast systemd[3106]: unity7.service: Killing process 3168258 (n/a) with signal SIGKILL.
Aug 26 23:17:38 beast systemd[3106]: unity7.service: Killing process 3168265 (n/a) with signal SIGKILL.
Aug 26 23:17:38 beast systemd[3106]: unity7.service: Failed with result 'core-dump'.
Aug 26 23:17:38 beast systemd[3106]: unity7.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 4.
Aug 26 23:17:38 beast systemd[3106]: Stopped target User systemd services for the Unity graphical session.
Aug 26 23:17:38 beast systemd[3106]: Stopping User systemd services for the Unity graphical session.
Aug 26 23:17:38 beast systemd[3106]: Stopped Unity Shell v7.
```

Any ideas as to what I can try to stop it?

Comment: Smells like OOM error which auto-terminates the heaviest task?

Comment: I'm currently at 11/32G RAM and 0/64G swap used, so it's unlikely to be that simple. But I'll monitor it.